# Создан специфический метод анонимного класса, но обратиться к нему нельзя

Tags: java

Разбираюсь со статьей https://javarush.com/groups/posts/2193-anonimnihe-klassih и не могу получить аналогичный результат в IDEA. Я создала интерфейс и анонимный класс со специфическим методом, но IDEA не принимает такой код как в статье и требует указать сигнатуру метода в интерфейсе. Почему?

```
public interface MonitoringSystem {

public void startMonitoring();

}

public class TipesOfClasses {

public static void main(String[] args) {


MonitoringSystem generalModule = new MonitoringSystem() {
    @Override
    public void startMonitoring() {
        System.out.println("Общий мониторинг");
    }
    public void someSpecificMethod() {
        System.out.println("Специфический метод");
    }
};
MonitoringSystem errorModule = new MonitoringSystem() {
    @Override
    public void startMonitoring() {
        System.out.println("Мониторинг ошибок");
    }
};
       
    generalModule.startMonitoring();
//Здесь IDEA подчеркивает красным метод someSpecificMethod()
    generalModule.someSpecificMethod();
        
    }
     
    }
```

Comment: В статье по указанной ссылке отсутствует вызов метода `someSpecificMethod`, автор не перепроверил свой код. О самой "проблеме" указано как минимум в двух комментариях к статье.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой трюк до 11 версии вряд ли возможен без создание нового типа. По сути вы ограничиваете доступные методы типом `MonitoringSystem` который знать не знает про метод `someSpecificMethod()`. Естественно получаете ошибку компиляции.

Начиная с 11 версии появилось ключевое слово `var`, с помощью которого тип объекта выводится "на лету":

```
 var generalModule = new MonitoringSystem() {
            @Override
            public void startMonitoring() {
                System.out.println("Общий мониторинг");
            }
            public void someSpecificMethod() {
                System.out.println("Специфический метод");
            }
        };
 generalModule.someSpecificMethod(); // no error
```

Переменная `generalModule` получает динамически сформированный тип (анонимный тип), который всё знает о методах анонимного класса (в том числе и новых) и позволяет ими пользоваться.

А что по поводу ссылки, которую вы указали - я не нашёл там места, где новый метод используется вне анонимного класса. Да, добавлять можно, но пользоваться только внутри.